# ReactJS route optional ID URL param

Tags: url, routes, reactjs

So, I've tried all this but none of them work.

```
<Route name="create-course" handler={CreateCourse} path="/course-builder/create-course/{:id}" />
<Route name="create-course" handler={CreateCourse} path="/course-builder/create-course/[:id]" />
<Route name="create-course" handler={CreateCourse} path="/course-builder/create-course{/id}" />
```

variants of the same error:

```
Error: Invariant Violation: Missing "id" parameter for path "/course-builder/create-course/{:id}"
```

/{:id?} one doesn't throw an error but URL becomes

```
/course-builder/create-course/%7B%7D
```

Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After param `:id` add `?`, like so

```
<Route name="create-course" handler={CreateCourse} path="/course-builder/create-course/:id?" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles upon this question - as of React-Router v1.0.0 the correct syntax is:

```
<Route name="create-course" handler={CreateCourse} path="/course-builder/create-course(/:id)" />
```

Documentation [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md#path-syntax)